# En c++ aparece la advertencia "warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]"

Tags: c++

#### metodo = `find`, `npos`

Aprendiendo sobre los métodos de `string` y usando `find`, me apareció una advertencia ejecutando el código en un compilador web. Pero al usar el mismo código en otro compilador (code::blocks 16.01) no me aparece tal advertencia.

Busqué información en internet, pero como la mayoría está en inglés, no he comprendido nada, y peor aún cuando lo traduje al español.

Quería preguntarles de qué se trata la advertencia:

> `10:14: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]`

#### El código fuente:

Lo que hace el código es buscar si en la palabra que ingresaste hay un `de` y te dice donde está

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string s;
   cin >> s;
   const int p = s.find("de");
   if (p != s.npos) {//aqui aparece la advertencia
      cout << p << endl;
   } else {
      cout << "No." << endl;
   }
}
```

El link del compilador + el código: http://cpp.sh/3pir

**Nota**: originalmente donde aparece la advertencia había un `string::npos`, el cual lo modifiqué a `s.npos` .

Comment: Te está avisando que estás comparando dos tipos distintos de entero, uno con signo y el otro sin, generalmente funciona ok pero te avisa para que lo tengas en cuenta.

Comment: @alan con el signo te refieres al punto.¿verdad?

Comment: me refiero a  si es negativo o positivo el número. Los `Int` y `unsigned int` no poseen punto.

Comment: Esta advertencia es de esas que conviene tener en cuenta. El tipo de s.npos es size_t, que es un tipo "integral" sin signo, y su tamaño depende del sistema (generalmente, sizeof(size_t) va a ser 32 en una arquitectura de 32 bits y 64 en una arquitectura de 64 bits. Estudia este asunto con un par de ejemplos y verás que tu programa va a mostrar distintos resultados dependiendo de dónde lo compiles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Formato de números con y sin signo en binario.

Los ordenadores almacenan números en binario; como no puedes guardar el símbolo de negativo `-` *binariamente*, se usa (habitualmente) el bit de más peso para marcar el signo del número.

Pondré un ejemplo con 8 bits:

```
|sgno|             numero               |
|bit7|bit6|bit5|bit4|bit3|bit2|bit1|bit0|
|  1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |  1 | = 129 (sin signo) -127 (con signo)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  1 | = 1   (sin signo)    1 (con signo)
```

En un número de 8bits, el 7º es el bit de más peso. Si ese bit está a valor `1` Y el tipo es con signo el valor corresponde a `-127`; si el tipo es sin signo su valor corresponde a `129` ¡una gran diferencia!.

La cantidad de [números que puede contener un tipo](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) de 8bits es 2<sup>8</sup> (256), cuando se usa el bit de signo la mitad de esos 256 números serán positivos y la otra mitad negativos, así que:

```
                                 |mínimo|máximo|
unsigned char (8 bits sin signo) |    0 |  255 |
  signed char (8 bits con signo) |  127 | -127 |
```

Estos rangos de números pueden cambiar según si el complemento binario es [a uno](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_a_uno) o [a dos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_a_dos).

#### ¿Por qué es este formato importante?

Como has podido ver, según si el número tiene o no tiene signo su valor cambia **mucho**, así que no es aconsejable compararlos aunque sea posible.

Se muestra un `warning` en lugar de un error porque es posible y correcto comparar tipos con singo y tipos sin signo siempre y cuando se comparen en el rango positivo de números... pero si se comparan tipos con singo contra tipos sin signo cuando los con signo están en el rango negativo, entonces pueden darse resultados inesperados.

El compilador no puede preveer a priori todas las operaciones que puedan hacerse con los números que intervienen en la comparación; así que *prevée* que *cabe la posibilidad* de que se haga una comparación potencialmente peligrosa: de ahí la alarma, en lugar de error.

La decisión que toma el compilador al comparar tipos con y sin signo está redactada en el [estándar C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)  apartado §4.7.2 (la traducción es mía):

> Si el tipo de destino es sin signo, el valor resultante es el menor entero sin signo congruente con el entero de origen (modulo 2n donde n es el número de bits usado para representar el tipo sin signo). [ *Nota:* en representaciones numéricas de complemento a dos, esta conversión es conceptual y no hay cambio en el patrón de bits (si no hay truncado) - *fin de la nota* ]

Mientras que en el apartado §5.9.10 (la traducción es mía):

> Varios operadores binarios que esperan operadores de tipo aritmético o enumerado causan conversiones y devuelven tipos de una manera similar. El propósito es devolver un tipo común, que es también el tipo del resultado. Este patrón es llamado *conversiones aritméticas usuales*, que se define así:
>
> ...
>
> - 10.5 ... las promociones integrales deben ser aplicadas a ambos operandos. Entonces las siguientes reglas serán aplicadas a los operandos promocionados:
>
>   - 10.5.1 Si ambos operandos tienen el mismo tipo, no se requiere ningia conversión adicional.
>   - 10.5.2 En caso contrario, si ambos operandos tienen tipos con signo o ambos tipos tienen tipos sin signo, el operando con el tipo con menor rango será convertido al tipo con mayor rango.
>   - 10.5.3 En caso contrario, si el operando que tiene tipo entero sin signo tiene un rango mayor o igual al rango del tipo del otro operando, el operando con tipo entero con signo debe ser convertido al tipo del operando con tipo entero sin signo.
>   - 10.5.4 En caso contrario, si el tipo del operando con tipo entero con signo puede representar todos los valores del tipo del operando entero sin signo, el poerando con tipo entero sin signo debe ser convertido al tipo con el operando con tipo entero con signo.
>   - 10.5.5 En caso contrario, ambos operandos deben ser convertidos a tipo entero sin signo correspondiendo al tipo del operando entero sin signo.

Este galimatías (el estándar suele ser complicado de entender) significa que si comparas tipos con signo contra tipos sin signo (o viceversa) se harán conversiones de tipos. Cabe la posibilidad que estas conversiones no te convengan o den lugar a resultados inesperados y/o indeseados.

#### Vale, lo pillo... ¿qué debo hacer?

Intenta usar siempre los mismos tipos para realizar comparaciones, si no conoces el tipo de una expresión puedes consultarlo en el código fuente o usar las herramientas del lenguaje para auto-detectarlo (C++11 o superior).

En tu caso, [la función `std::string::find`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) devuelve un `size_type` [el cuál es un alias](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string#member_types) del `size_type` de su allocator el cuál suele ser un alias de [`size_t`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) (es algo más complicado, pero ya hemos tenido suficientes complicaciones por ahora). Y lo comparas contra [`std::string::npos`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) cuyo tipo es el `size_type` del que ya hemos hablado. Así que podrías cambiar tu código a:

```
const size_t p = s.find("de");
if (p != s.npos) {
```

Lo que posiblemente eliminaría el error, o usar el tipo `size_type` interno de `std::string`:

```
const string::size_type p = s.find("de");
if (p != s.npos) {
```

Lo cuál eliminaría el error con toda seguridad, o auto-detectar el tipo:

```
const auto p = s.find("de");
if (p != s.npos) {
```

O si sospechamos que `std::string::npos` es de un tipo diferente al retorno de `std::string::find` podríamos copiar el tipo con [decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

```
const decltype(s.npos) p = s.find("de");
if (p != s.npos) {
```

#### No se vayan, aún hay más.

> me apareció una advertencia ejecutando el código en un compilador web. Pero al usar el mismo código en otro compilador (code::blocks 16.01) no me aparece tal advertencia.

La máquina usada en la compilación web y la máquina en que tienes instalado code::blocks pueden tener arquitecturas diferentes y diferentes implementaciones de las librerías de `C++`.

Arquitecturas diferentes pueden tener diferentes tamaños de tipos enteros por defecto y diferentes librerías de `C++` pueden tener definiciones diferentes de `string::size_type` y `size_t`, con lo que pueden estar realizandose conversiones diferentes o ninguna conversión, lo cuál puede acabar en no emitir ninguna alarma...

... o podría ser que tengas desactivadas las alarmas en tu configuración de code::blocks.

> **Nota**: originalmente donde aparece la advertencia había un `string::npos`, el cual lo modifiqué a `s.npos`.

[`npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) está definido **dentro** de la clase plantilla `std::basic_string` como:

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```

Es decir: es un miembro estático de [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), los miembros estáticos de una clase se pueden acceder sin instanciar la clase, a través del nombre de la misma, así que puedes escribir `string::npos`... pero como forma parte también de `string` puedes acceder a `npos` desde una instancia, así que **también** puedes escribir `s.npos` y ambos son válidos. Pero esto último no es aconsejado.

Comment: debo preguntar.¿por que usar `s.npos` no es aconsejable?

Comment: @bassily esa pregunta es suficientemente buena como para merecer una pregunta propia, siéntete libre de redactarla ;) por el momento te diré que es menos confuso para otros programadores que lean el código :D

Answer (score 1):

Considera esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   int x;
   unsigned int y;
   x = 1;
   y = 1;
   printf("x=%d y=%u son %s\n", x,y ,x==y ? "iguales" : "distintos");
   x = -1;
   y = 0xffffffff;
   printf("x=%d y=%u son %s\n", x,y, x==y ? "iguales" : "distintos");
   return 0;
}
```

En mi caso (depende del compilador y arquitectura) esto compila sin advertencias y al correr imprime:

```
x=1 y=1 son iguales
x=-1 y=4294967295 son iguales
```

En la anteúltima linea la variable `x` vale -1. Dado que la variable `y` está declarada como `unsigned int` (entero sin signo, es decir, nunca negativo) 
uno diría que la comparación `x == y` debería retornar siempre falso, porque nunca un valor negativo puede ser igual uno que (por cómo está declarado) es positivo. Pero cuando `C` se ve obligado a comparar tipos distintos automáticamente convierte uno de ellos (automatic cast). En este caso, el valor de `y` se interpreta como signado, y entonces en lugar de interpretarse como `0xFFFFFFFF=68719476735` se interpreta como signado (complemento a dos), lo cual da el valor `-1`. Por eso la comparación retorna VERDADERO.

Esto, naturalmente, es peligroso. Por eso el compilador puede arrojarte una advertencia ("para comparar estos tipos, de los cuales uno es signado y otro no, me voy a ver obligado a convertir uno de ellos ¿estás seguro de que esto no te traerá problemas?").

En nuestro caso concreto, si miramos la documentación de [npos](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) vemos que (al igual que `find`) no retorna un `int` sino un [`size_t`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stddef.h), que es un [entero no signado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stddef.h), de tamaño dependiente del compilador (normalmente equivale a un `unsigned int`).

Por eso, al hacer `p != s.npos` estamos comparando un entero signado con uno no signado. En nuestro caso, esto no es peligroso, pero el compilador no puede saberlo y por eso nos advierte.

Si quieres remediarlo, puedes forzar el cast

```
if(p != (int)s.npos)
```

o, mejor, declarar la variable con el tipo correcto:

```
const size_t p = s.find("de");
```

Comment: La respuesta es buena y válida... para `C`: has usado funciones y cabeceras de `C`, mas la respuesta está etiquetada como `C++`.

Comment: usando la formula de "`if(p != (int)s.npos)`" no me aparece el error