# ¿Por qué usar `n.pos`no es aconsejable?

Tags: c++

En una de las respuestas que me dieron, al final de ella me aconsejaron no usar `s.npos` y usar en cambio `string::npos`.

Como no conozco mucho de C++ les quiero pedir si me pueden explicar por que es mas aconsejable el 1er metodo y no el 2do.

Derivado de esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22122/en-c-aparece-la-advertencia-warning-comparison-between-signed-and-unsigned-i/22158?noredirect=1#comment35706_22158).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npos` está definido dentro de la clase plantilla `std::basic_string` como:

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```

Es decir: es un miembro estático de una clase y por ello no pertenece a ninguna instancia si no a la clase; usar la notación de acceso a miembro de clase oculta ese hecho y puede dar lugar a confusión (como [ya ha comentado Jose Antonio Dura Olmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22710/2742)).

#### Detalles técnicos sobre miembros estáticos.

Según el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) en el punto `§9.4.2.1` (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 9.4.2 Datos miembro estáticos
>
> 1. Un dato miembro declarado como `static` **no forma parte de los sub-objetos de la clase**. Si un dato miembro estático es declarado cmo `thread_local` existirá una copia del miembro por cada hilo. Si un dato miembro estático no es delcarado como `thread_local` **existirá una instancia del miembro que será compartida por todos los objetos de la clase**.

La parte más importante de lo resaltado es el hecho de que un miembro estático **no forma parte de los sub-objetos de la clase**. Es decir: en el caso que nos ocupa `npos` no forma parte de ninguna [instancia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instancia_(inform%C3%A1tica)) de `std::basic_string` si no que pertenece a la clase en si y en consecuencia todas las instancias acceden a la misma copia de la variable miembro.

El propio estándar indica que se puede acceder a los miembros estáticos de clases (variables o funciones) usando la notación de acceso miembro en el punto `§9.4.2` (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 9.4 Miembros estáticos
>
> 2. Un miembro estático `s` de una clase `X` puede ser accedido usando la expresión `X::s`; **no es necesario usar la sintaxis de acceso a miembro de clase para referirse a un miembro estático**. Un miembro estático puede ser accedido usando la sintaxis de acceso a miembro de clase, en ese caso la expresión del objeto es evaluada [*Ejemplo:*
>
>    ```
>    struct process {
>        static void reschedule();
>    };
>    process& g();
>
>    void f() {
>        process::reschedule(); // CORRECTO: no se necesita instancia
>        g().reschedule(); // llamada a g()
>    }
>    ```
>
>    —*fin del ejemplo* ]

Así que los miembros estáticos de una clase se pueden acceder con la notación estática (`Clase::miembro`) o con la notación de miembro de instancia (`Clase c; c.miembro`)... por lo que cabe preguntarse:

#### ¿Por qué una notación debería preferirse frente a la otra?

Suponiendo que tenemos estas dos estructuras:

```
struct A { int a{};        };
struct B { static int b{}; };
```

Veamos cómo funcionan en código:

```
A a; B b; // Instanciamos A y B.
std::cout << A::a << '\n'; // Error de compilacion
std::cout << a.a  << '\n'; // Muestra 0
std::cout << B::b << '\n'; // Muestra 0
std::cout << b.b  << '\n'; // Muestra 0
```

El miembro `a` de `A` sólo existe cuando se instancia `A`, de ahí que al intentar leer su valor surja un error de compilación. Por otro lado el miembro `b` de `B` existe con o sin instancia de `B`.

Dado que la notación `Clase::miembro` *sólo* funciona con miembros estáticos<sup>1</sup> y la notación `instancia.miembro` o `instancia->miembro` funciona con miembros estáticos y con miembros de instancia nos encontramos que la segunda notación puede ser ambigua mientras que la primera es precisa.

Para no caer en la ambigüedad es mejor usar la notación más precisa, no hacerlo puede ser confuso para otros programadores o para uno mismo.

#### ¿En algún caso puede ser más provechosa la notación `instancia.miembro_estatico`?

Me cuesta pensar en alguna situación en que acceder a un miembro estático mediante la notación de accesoa miembro de clase sea la mejor opción. Lo más parecido sería un código genérico en que las clases utilizadas sean explícitamente ambiguas y por ello se pudiera sacar provecho de la ambigüedad del acceso mediante punto (`.`) o flecha (`->`):

```
struct Banana { int calorias_por_gramo{};        };
struct Papaya { static int calorias_por_gramo{}; };

template <typename FRUTA>
void muestra_calorias_de(FRUTA f, float gramos)
{
    std::cout << "Tiene " << f.calorias_por_gramo * gramos << "calorías\n";
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior recibimos un tipo (`FRUTA`) que sabemos que tiene un miembro `calorias_por_gramo`, pero en unos tipos el miembro es estático y en otros no; si tuvieramos que crear una función para la versión con miembro estático y otra función para la versión con miembro no estático el código se complicaría.

#### Si la notación puede ser ambigua ¿por qué esta permitida?

En las primeras versiones de C++ las únicas sintaxis de acceso a miembros (estáticos o no) era el punto (`.`) y la flecha (`->`); dado que no existía una sintaxis concreta para acceder a datos que no requirieran instancia los programadores hacían uso de lo único disponible:

```
struct B { static int b{}; };
std::cout << (B*(0))->b << '\n'; // Muestra 0
```

El código anterior transforma el valor `0` en un puntero a la clase `B` y acto seguido accede mediante la flecha `->` al miembro `b` de dicha instancia; al ser `b` un miembro estático no es necesario evaluar el puntero que apunta a `0` y no salta un error en tiempo de ejecución.

Cuando C++ evolucionó e incorporó el operador `::` no se eliminó la sintaxis anterior.

#### Conclusión.

El propio estándar de C++ permite (posiblemente por motivos históricos) el acceso a miembros estáticos de objetos mediante la notación de miembros no estáticos; pero esa notación es ambigua ya que pueden confundirse con acceso a miembros no estáticos, para evitar dicha confusión se aconseja usar la notación `Clase::miembro_estático` para desambiguar.

---

<sup>1</sup>Esa notación funciona en otros contextos (por ejemplo punteros a miembros) pero ese es otro tema.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando un programador ve `Clase::miembro` sabe que se está accediendo al miembro estático de una clase. Lo cual significa que ese miembro no está asociado a ningún objeto, es posible invocarlo pese a que no se haya creado ningún objeto de esa Clase.

Cuando ve `objeto.otroMiembro` sabe que puede que se esté accediendo a un miembro de una instacia o a un miembro estático. Pero dado que hay una nomenclatura que es exclusiva para miembros estáticos lo habitual es dejar esta otra nomenclatura solo para los miembros de instancia. Y si trabajas con gente que sabes que programa así resulta más fácil y rápido entender su código.

Se trata de una convención. Una regla no escrita (o sí escrita en ciertas guías de estilo) que facilita el trabajo en equipo. Por tanto es una recomendación de estilo. A nivel de código compilado no hay diferencia entre una cosa y otra.

Nótese que hay ocasiones en que sí puede ser necesario el uso de objeto.miembro para acceder a miembros estáticos, concretamente cuando en programación de plantillas quieres acceder a un miembro estático sin disponer del tipo pero sí de un objeto de ese tipo.