# memset no funciona con numeros grandes

Tags: c++, c++11

Tengo el siguiente simple código:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define oo 0xffffff
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int v[10];
    memset(v, oo, sizeof(v));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << v[i] << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Se supone que el `memset` debería seterar todos los valores a 0xffffff, pero cuando imprimo el arreglo sale esto:

```
$g++ -std=c++11 -o main *.cpp
$main
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

Sin embargo, no he tenido problemas cuando los valores a setear son 0 o -1. ¿A qué se debe?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: pregunto: esto 0xffffff no es 65535 que es -1 para un entero?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, ese numero es 16777215 en decimal. Aún cuando no se quiera considerar ese número, poniendo `memset(v, 35, sizeof(v))` arroja como resultado 589505315 para cada una de las posiciones del arreglo.

Comment: pero estas usando un int.. o sea.. vas hasta 65534...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La culpa de este comportamiento es de [`memset`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset), cuya firma es:

```
void* memset( void* dest, int ch, std::size_t count );
```

Esta función convierte el valor pasado como segundo parámetro a `char` y lo copia tantas veces como indique el tercer parámetro en cada uno de los caracteres del objeto apuntado por el primer parámetro.

Así pues, el valor `0xffffff` de tipo entero (`int`) es convertido a tipo caracter (`char`). En arquitecturas de 32bits un entero puede contener 2<sup>32</sup> valores<sup>†</sup> mientras que un caracter habitualmente puede contener 2<sup>8</sup> valores<sup>‡</sup>. Al pasar un tipo de mayor tamaño a uno de menor tamaño se produce un truncamiento de manera que pasamos de valor `0xffffff` a valor `0xff`. El valor `0xff` en un tipo caracter con signo<sup>※</sup> (`char`) corresponde a `-1` así que copia ese valor en el puntero apuntado por `dest` hasta alcanzar `count` copias.

> Lo que no entiendo es por qué si asigno los valores con un for en vez de con memset funciona como entero sin signo.

Cuando copias en un bucle `for` en lugar de usando `memset` no hay transformaciones de tipos y asignas exáctamente el valor `0xffffff` (16.777.215 en tipo `int`) no el valor `0xff` (`-1` en tipo `char`).

> ffffff es 16777215, por qué aparecería 4294967295 si no es el valor real del hexadecimal que se está asignando?

`0xffffff` (seis f) es 16.777.215 y `0xffffffff` (ocho f) es 4.294.967.295. Me equivoqué al leer tu pregunta, tienes razón, no aparecerá `4294967295` a no ser que asignes `0xffffffff`

> Probé cambiando `copy` por `fill` y funcionó.

Otro fallo mío, muy bien visto :)

---

**Respuesta anterior, no relevante**. La conserfo para que sigan teniendo sentido los comentarios.

El código está funcionando perfectamente. El valor `0xffffffff` en un número **entero con signo** es `-1`, para entender por qué [te recomiendo leer este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22122/en-c-aparece-la-advertencia-warning-comparison-between-signed-and-unsigned-i/22158).

Si cambias `int v[10];` por `unsigned v[10];` obtendrás:

> ```
> 4294967295
> 4294967295
> 4294967295
> 4294967295
> 4294967295
> 4294967295
> 4294967295
> 4294967295
> 4294967295
> 4294967295
> ```

Pero en C++ no deberías estar usando `memset`, usa `std::copy`:

```
copy(begin(v), end(v), oo);
```

Aunque si querías rellenar `v` con `0xffffffff` podías hacerlo en tiempo de compilación en lugar de en tiempo de ejecución:

```
int v[10] { 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff};
```

---

<sup>†</sup>Cuatro mil doscientos noventa y cuatro millones novecientos sesenta y siete mil doscientos noventa y seis valores diferentes.

<sup>‡</sup>Doscientos cincuenta y seis valores diferentes.

<sup>※</sup>El tipo `char` puede tener o no tener signo, es dependiente de plataforma.

Comment: Joya está claro! Lo que no entiendo es por qué si asigno los valores con un for en vez de con memset funciona como entero sin signo

Comment: Ahí probé cambiando `copy` por `fill` y funcionó correctamente!

Comment: Otra cosa, ffffff es 16777215, por qué aparecería 4294967295 si no es el valor real del hexadecimal que se está asignando? Disculpame las molestias y las preguntas recurrentes!

Comment: ahhh tenia razon!!!! :p +1

Comment: Me acabo de fijar que tu macro `oo` es `0xffffff` (seis f) no `0xffffffff` (ocho f). Estoy cambiando la respuesta.

Comment: Excelente respuesta! Mil gracias!